# Keep Promise Array order in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a question about promise all and the resulting order. As sample I use:

```
async function getControlFile(testcases, timeout, uptimeout){


    //2.) Löschen der Testcafe Steuerungsdatei zum neu Schreiben.
    fs.unlinkSync(__basedir + '/tests/temp.js');

    //3.) Öffen des Streams zum Schreiben der Steuerungsdatei
    var logger = fs.createWriteStream(__basedir + '/tests/temp.js', {
        flags: 'a' // 'a' means appending (old data will be preserved)
    });

    //Zuerst den Header schreiben.
    //Wir schreiben den Login/Pass einmal hinzu.
    logger.write('import { Selector, Role } from \'testcafe\';'+'\n');
    logger.write('import inputStore from \'../config/input-store\';'+'\n\n');

    //Tester Rolle Schreiben damit wir nicht immer neu einloggen müssen.
    logger.write('const bc3Tester = Role(inputStore.metaUrl, async t => {'+'\n');
    logger.write('await t'+'\n');
    logger.write('   .typeText(Selector(\'#email\'), inputStore.clLogin, {'+'\n');
    logger.write('      caretPos: 0'+'\n');
    logger.write('   })'+'\n');
    logger.write('   .typeText(Selector(\'#password\'), inputStore.clPassword, {'+'\n');
    logger.write('       caretPos: 0'+'\n');
    logger.write('   })'+'\n');
    logger.write('   .click(Selector(\'span\').withText(\'Login\'))'+'\n');
    logger.write('}, { preserveUrl: true });'+'\n\n');

    //4.) Fixture Datum festlegen.
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getDate()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getFullYear()+' ('+today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() + ':' + today.getSeconds()+')';
    var xTransformDate = today.getDate()+'_'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'_'+today.getFullYear()+'_'+today.getHours() + '_' + today.getMinutes() + '_' + today.getSeconds();


    logger.write('fixture `Clipcafe Run '+date+'`'+'\n\n');

    //HERE IT STARTS
    //The testcases array is an array of MongoDB __id to select them.
    //I do not know the amount of testcases. 
    await Promise.all(testcases.map(async (entryMain) => {
        await getTestData(entryMain, logger, timeout, uptimeout, xTransformDate);

    })).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Fehler beim Schreiben des Testscripts.");
        return;
    });


    console.log("logger end");
    // Fixture Schliessen
    logger.end();  // close string
```

The script will prepare a file and I use a promise all, with a map to an array of MongDB __id to create promises.

```
async function getTestData(id, klogger, timeout, uptimeout, dateString){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        Case.findById(id, function(err, tCase) {

            if (err)
                reject(err);


            var tempData = tCase.data;

            //Replace timeouts
            tempData = tempData.replace(/%%TIMEOUT%%/g,timeout);
            tempData = tempData.replace(/%%UPLOAD%%/g,uptimeout);

            tempData = tempData.replace(/%%FOLDER1%%/g,"testfolder1"+dateString);
            tempData = tempData.replace(/%%FOLDER2%%/g,"testfolder2"+dateString);

            tempData = tempData.replace(/%%IMAGE1%%/g,"testimage1"+dateString);
            tempData = tempData.replace(/%%IMAGE2%%/g,"testimage2"+dateString);

            tempData = tempData.replace(/%%IMAGE3%%/g,"testrenamed"+dateString);

            //Ende Jury Fixure

            klogger.write(tempData + '\n');


            klogger.write('\n\n');


            resolve('true');

        });

    });
};
```

My problem is now, that the order inside the file is not the order of the given Array. The order is basing on the time the Mongo request need.

I read , that the final order will always the order of the input, but I also read that the the promise.all promises are working async.

So how I can make it, that the final order in the file is the same order as the input Mongo __id array?

Comment: Promise.all doesn't run them sequentially! You have to choose another way.

Comment: *that the order inside the file is not the order of the given Array* Where does that array exists? Inside database or somewhere else?

Comment: @Ashh `Promise.all(testcases.map(async (entryMain) => ...))`

Comment: @Ashh Each callback creates an entry in the log file (`klogger.write()`), but those entries don't match the order of the corresponding entries in `testcases`

Comment: Instead of calling `logger.write` in a promise, `return` the data you want to write, and write it all at once after `Promise.all` completes

Comment: @georg Why? The promise is resolved after written. So it do not make any difference to my problem the the final order is not the input order. The trouble maker is the mongo request.

Comment: @ingo: let's just try that ;)

Comment: @George, I tried that before I comment. It is the same order. The fast mongo requests are first before the slow requests.

Comment: have you tried `promise.allSettled()` or `Promise Chaining` is useful for you if order is important one by one to resolve.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I tried with allSettled, but no difference.

Comment: @ingo and what about promise chaining ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda As I understand I need for each promise a -then. But I do not know the amount of promises before, so I am a little bit lost with chaining.

Comment: @ingo https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/347/javascript-promises-mastering-the-asynchronous/chaining-the-promises this link may help you